# How to extend a wild card option to include js and ts

Tags: alias, pattern-matching

I have an alias set as follows:

`alias ppp='prettier --write "**/*.js"'`

I want it also to do all my .ts files.  I'm quite inept at wild card expressions sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, if you're using bash or something like it, you could try:

```
alias ppp='prettier --write "**/*.{js,ts}"'
```

Comment: Thanks (and thanks for not making fun of my question).  Next time I'll know. My trick count is now ++

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
alias ppp='prettier --write "**/*.js";prettier --write "**/*.ts"'
```